# Rtsp stream with onvif metadata stream

Tags: rtsp, onvif

Can you tell me if there are test rtsp streams including onvif stream of metadata? I have not got a ip camera. Thanks

Comment: the only free rtsp stream available online i know is the big buck bunny one... I'm not sure it still works. rtsp://184.72.239.149/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mov

Comment: @LoukMo this resource is no longer working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [happytimesoft-onvifserver](http://www.happytimesoft.com/products/onvif-server/index.html) to develop the onvif client.

It supports

1. IP Configuration
2. Device Discovery
3. Device Service
4. Media Service
5. OSD Setting
6. Image Setting
7. PTZ Management
8. PTZ Motion Control
9. Recording control
10. Recording search
11. Recording replay
12. Video analytics
13. Event Polling
14. Event Notification
15. Access Control

Basically happytimesoft-onvifserver is free onvif server designed to help to implement onvif client.
Currently it is available for linux and windows.

For RTSP streaming it uses your computer web cam and provides its rtsp url for streaming.